# How to encrypt a string using python Openssl public key?

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

My current code to generate an OpenSSL public-private key pair:

```py
import OpenSSL

key = OpenSSL.crypto.PKey()
key.generate_key(OpenSSL.crypto.TYPE_RSA, 2048)
public_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_publickey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)
private_key = OpenSSL.crypto.dump_privatekey(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, key)
print(public_key, private_key, sep="\n")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation recommends that you call [key.to_cryptography_key()](https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.PKey.to_cryptography_key) to get a cryptographic key, and then use pyca/cryptography to perform the encryption.

https://www.pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html

Given your crypto key:

```
result = crypto_key.encrypt(b"Hello there")
```

---

I should add, RSA is primary intended for signatures and verification, and key exchange.  It's way too slow for general encryption.

Comment: Yes, I do know that RSA is slow am using it to send symmetric keys across a server client.

Comment: Sorry then.  Just making sure.  When someone says "I want to encrypt using RSA", I need to both answer the question and make sure they understand what they're doing!  But hopefully I did answer your question.